# Django doesn't update sqlite_master upon table rename

Tags: django, django-models, sqlite, database-migration

Is there a reason why Django doesn't update sqlite_master records when a table is renamed using **migrations.AlterModelTable**?

I have a table that needs to be renamed, when I run:

```
ALTER TABLE old_name RENAME TO new_name;
```

All sqlite_master records from tables that have old_name.id as the foreign key gets updated correctly, **REFERENCES "old_name" ("id")** turns into **REFERENCES "new_name" ("id")**.

But this doesn't happen when I use **migrations.AlterModelTable** inside a migration.

My code:

```
operations = [
    migrations.AlterModelTable(name='Sample', table='new_name'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug currently blocking Django 2.0 release.

https://github.com/django/django/pull/9389

Comment: Thanks. Too bad, I guess it's safer to wait.

Comment: @user2937998 FWIW Django 2.0 has been released for a while so you should be able to use it now.